# Error on Password Change Of Active Directory User

Tags: c#, active-directory

Hi I am trying to reset password of Active Directory User But I Am getting error,Following is my Code:

```
    public string ChangePassword(string Identity,string OldPassword, string Password)
 {
      string success = "Success";
      try
      {


          DirectoryEntry UserEntry = null;
          DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://.../DC=Domain,DC=COM", Identity, OldPassword);

          DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
          SearchResult resultsearch = search.FindOne();
          if (resultsearch == null)
          {
              success = "User Not Found In This Domain";
          }
          else
          {

              success = "find";
              UserEntry = resultsearch.GetDirectoryEntry();
              UserEntry.Username = @"Domain\Administrator";
              UserEntry.Password = "password";
              UserEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;

              if (UserEntry == null)
                  success = "User Not Found In This Domain";
              else
              {
                  try
                  {
                      success = UserEntry.Username.ToString();


    UserEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { OldPassword, Password });
                      UserEntry.CommitChanges();

                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      success = ex.ToString();
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          success = ex.ToString();
      }
```

So I am getting Error in **UserEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { OldPassword, Password });
                          UserEntry.CommitChanges();**

Error:

```
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020006): Unknown name.           (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))
        at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
        at WebService.ChangePassword(String Identity, String OldPassword, String Password) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\App_Code\WebService.cs:line 370
```

Comment: @Michael Todd Yes,I just Change name but its correct DOmain and I have Administrator rights.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the newer `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` API's? It's `UserPrincipal` class _has_ a [`ChangePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.changepassword.aspx) method that works pretty well.

Comment: Yes I can understand that it seems like API not include changepassword method,@M.Babcock-I use system.DirectoryServices.dll ,Should I use any other dll file?

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll

Comment: @M.Babcock ,My Application is running on version 2.0 so I think I can not use DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Any Other Suggetion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET Framework 3.5 or later, the code below will solve the problem. Class definition is omitted.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public static string ChangePassword(string adminUser, string adminPassword,
    string domain, string container, string userName, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext principalContext = 
            new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, container, 
                adminUser, adminPassword);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);
        if (user == null) return "User Not Found In This Domain";

        user.SetPassword(newPassword);
        return user.Name;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ChangePassword(@"DOMAIN\Administrator", "password", "DOMAIN",
  "DC=Domain,DC=COM", userName, newPassword);
```

EDIT: Added a version for .NET 2.0 framework.

A change password method for .NET 2.0:

```
public static string ChangePassword20(string adminUser, string adminPassword,
    string container, string domainController, string userName, string newPassword)
{
    const AuthenticationTypes authenticationTypes = AuthenticationTypes.Secure |
        AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;

    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = null;
    DirectorySearcher searcher = null;
    DirectoryEntry userEntry = null;

    try
    {
        searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", 
            domainController, container), 
            adminUser, adminPassword, authenticationTypes);

        searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
        searcher.Filter = String.Format("sAMAccountName={0}", userName);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.CacheResults = false;

        SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne(); ;
        if (searchResult == null) return "User Not Found In This Domain";

        userEntry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

        userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
        userEntry.CommitChanges();

        return "New password set";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (userEntry != null) userEntry.Dispose();
        if (searcher != null) searcher.Dispose();
        if (searchRoot != null) searchRoot.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ChangePassword20(@"DOMAIN\Administrator", "password", "DC=Domain,DC=COM",
    "domainControllerName", "userName", "newPassword");
```

Comment: Thanks Espen,I can Reset my Password now but I need to run my application in .net 4.0, I want to run it in framework 2.0 because o f requirement,can you tell me why I can not use directotyentry.invoke() ??

Comment: If you have administrator rights, the correct method to set password is to use Invoke("SetPassword"). The change password method requires that the old password is known. The trick is to initialize the searchRoot directory entry with correct credentials and AuthenticationTypes.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- You should not be setting a username, password, or AuthN type on `UserEntry`.
- your success = `UserEntry.Username...` should be `obj foo = UserEntry.NativeObject;`. If that passes, you have a valid DE.
- You don't need to call `CommitChanges()` here.
- You would call ChangePassword in the context of the user, not the administrator. That will pass through the `GetDirectoryEntry()` call properly.

Comment: I try all of above still not get it.