# Updating password of user in active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am  trying to change the password of a particular user 
you can  find code below

```
var directoryEntryObject = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<IP>","administraor", "password");
baseObject.directoryEntryObject.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "test@123" });
baseObject.directoryEntryObject.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0;
baseObject.directoryEntryObject.Close();
```

Now i am  getting below Error ::

> Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006
>   (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

Comment: Or [Error on Password Change Of Active Directory User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200004/error-on-password-change-of-active-directory-user)

Comment: tried all of them bt none of them works :(

Answer (score 0):

administraor -> is this the real username you are trying? Check the spelling of the username, it is administrator.

If you just typed here with this mistake, try

```
var directoryEntryObject = 
        new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<IP>/Dc=domain,DC=local","administrtaor", "password");
```