# How to change password in ASP.NET using Directory LDAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, change-password

```js
<%@ Page Title="Change Password" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="FormsAuthAd.Account.ChangePassword" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="FormsAuthAd" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Change Password
    </h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to change your password.
    </p>
    <p>
        New passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
    </p>
    <asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangeUserPassword" runat="server" CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" 
         SuccessPageUrl="ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx">
        <ChangePasswordTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ChangeUserPasswordValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="changePassword">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Old Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Old Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." ToolTip="New Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Confirm New Password is required."
                             ToolTip="Confirm New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="NewPassword" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Confirm New Password must match the New Password entry."
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" CommandName="ChangePassword" Text="Change Password" 
                         ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup" OnClick="ChangePassword"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </ChangePasswordTemplate>
    </asp:ChangePassword>
</asp:Content>
```

i want to change my password using my web app using ASP.NET
but how to apply the new password to my ldap directory?
i still confuse, what should i write code to connect my change password app to ldap directory.

in logon form, i'm success to connected from my web app to ldap directory.
but i confuse to sent my new password to ldap directory.
can somebody help me, what should i do to complete this app?
thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

Assume user have inserted all required fields, create a method to change user's password on LDAP and attach it on page codebehind:

```
public static String ChangeUserPassword(String adminName, String adminPassword, String userName, String currentPassword, String newPassword, String domainController, String container)
{
    String ldapPath = String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", domainController, container); // this is your domain name
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, adminName, adminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
    String query = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", userName);

    ds.Filter = query;
    ds.Sort.PropertyName = "CN";
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.CacheResults = false;

    try
    {
        SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
        if (sr == null)
        {
            return "User name not found in this domain.";
        }
        DirectoryEntry userCredentials = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
        user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new Object[] { newPassword });
        user.CommitChanges();

        return "Password for " + userName + "changed successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // throw exception here
       return "An error occurred when trying to connect on LDAP service.";
    }
}
```

For .NET 3.5 and above:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public static String ChangeUserPassword(String adminName, String adminPassword, String userName, String currentPassword, String newPassword, String domainController, String container)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainController, container, adminName, adminPassword);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return "User name not found in this domain.";
        }

        user.SetPassword(newPassword);
        return "Password for " + userName + "changed successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // throw exception here
       return "An error occurred when trying to connect on LDAP service.";
    }
}
```

`currentPassword` and `newPassword` obtained from `asp:TextBox`, `userName` obtained from user's identity name.

Reference (with minor edits):

(1) http://forums.asp.net/t/558693.aspx?Change+a+Users+Password+in+Active+Directory (.NET 2.0)

(2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200460 (.NET 3.5 & above)

CMIIW.

Comment: what if I do not use the admin? I've made a connection to ldap. and use the user password. I can get into the system, what to change these passwords should use the admin? if I did not include the string admin name, what influence the system? thanks for answering.

Comment: some say that when I want to create a new password is updated to ldap directory then on the button change my password for onclik function, where this function will take classes from ldapauthentication.cs. but i am confused how to make the public to change the password and will connect to ldapauthentication. here's code for my ldapauthentication.cs:

Comment: i've make form logon.aspx and the form connect to ldapauthentication.cs
now if i want to changepassword from ChangePassword.aspx, how to connect and update password to ldapauthentication.cs?
thank you

Comment: Insert ldapauthentication.cs method into your ChangePassword.aspx.cs submit button onclick event handler. For user-based authentication try giving user's current password as context parameter, such as `DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, userName, currentPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);` or `PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainController, container, userName, currentPassword);`

Comment: so the method used on ldapauthentication and also in changepassword.aspx?

Comment: but i can't use user.Invoke in ldapauthentication.cs
the error says "the name does not exist in the current content"
what should i do?

Comment: ldapauthentication.cs used for defining the LDAP processing method, and ChangePassword.aspx.cs calling method inside ldapauthentication.cs. Please submit your ldapauthentication.cs code to let me know where "name does not exist" error encountered.

Comment: not enough character to commen my ldap.cs
can you give me your email address? so you can teach and help me
:)
thank you so much mr Tetsuya

Comment: Just edit your question briefly here to include code inside ldapauthentication.cs and ChangePassword.cs besides ChangePassword.aspx. I will inspect them A.S.A.P. to find the source of error. Thanks for your quick response, Yosua-san.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace FormsAuthAd.Account
{
    public partial class ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: i'm sorry, i put my ldapauthentication.cs code to answer option on this web

Comment: i put my ldapauthentication.cs and changepassword.aspx to answer option on this web
thanks before mr Tetsuya for your time and your knowledge

Comment: Where ChangeUserPassword() method called? I don't see any place you'd inserting that, then ldapPath should be declared as `String ldapPath = "LDAP://erpad-tbs-1.packet-systems.com"`. Also, you have potential naming conflict on ChangePassword.aspx.cs by declaring ID in `<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangeUserPassword" runat="server" CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" 
         SuccessPageUrl="ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx">`, thus change your LDAP auth method name.

Comment: so what should i do mister?
i've change method name, but stil same

Comment: Have you calling the method with correct parameters? Possible that error comes from duplicate namespaces, class names or property names. Check if the passwords are inserted properly, set multiple breakpoints on ldapauthentication.cs when debugging if you don't sure.

Comment: i change name on ldapauthentication tobe ChangePswd()

Comment: i used your code in my ldapauthentication.cs, but the problem is
user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new Object[] { newPassword });
user.CommitChanges();

error message: "the name 'user' does not exist in this current context "

so what should i do Mr. Tetsuya?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true -->
```

```
here's my changepassword.aspx
```

```js
<%@ Page Title="Change Password" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="FormsAuthAd.Account.ChangePassword" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="FormsAuth" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Change Password
    </h2>
    <p>
        Use the form below to change your password.
    </p>
    <p>
        New passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
    </p>
    <asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangeUserPassword" runat="server" CancelDestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" 
         SuccessPageUrl="ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx">
        <ChangePasswordTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ChangeUserPasswordValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="changePassword">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Old Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Old Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." ToolTip="New Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Confirm New Password is required."
                             ToolTip="Confirm New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="NewPassword" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Confirm New Password must match the New Password entry."
                             ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" CommandName="ChangePassword" Text="Change Password" 
                         ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup" OnClick="ChangePassword"/>
                </p>
            </div>

<script runat="server">
void ChangePassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string adPath = "LDAP://erpad-tbs-1.packet-systems.com"; //Path to your LDAP directory server
  LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);

  DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, userName, currentPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
}
</script>

        </ChangePasswordTemplate>
    </asp:ChangePassword>
</asp:Content>
```

here's my changepassword.aspx